# How to use the rails logger for classes/modules in the lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have classes/modules in my /lib folder that look like:

```
class MyClass
  def self.doSomething()
  end
end
```

How can I use the Rails logger for this class?

I have another class that doesn't have static methods like:

```
class OtherClass
  def initialize(param1, param2)
    @param1 = param1
    @param2 = param2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use `Rails.logger.info` or `Rails.logger.error` anywhere you want in that class.